# SQLite database in not accessed and values not retrieved

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite

I'm a beginner iPhone developer trying to take information out of a sqlite database in Xcode 4. I have my database (which is named DB_Info.sqlite) in the same directory as my .h and .m files, and I also dragged the database into the folders section on the left bar in Xcode. 
Could you please take a quick look at my code and let me know where my mistake is?

```objc
#import "MyDatabase.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"

    enter code here

@implementation MyDatabase


-(NSMutableArray *) OpenMyDatabase: (NSString *)query:(NSString *)column
{
    //store the database name here
    self.databaseName=@"App_Database.sqlite";

    //get the reference of the database to be stored in device or emulator
    FMDatabase *database=[self openDatabase: self.databaseName];

    //open the database
    [database open];

    //fetch a collumn from database and store it in array
   // NSArray *nsarr= [self storeDatabaseColumnInArray: database: @"select id from kas":@"id"];
    NSMutableArray *nsarr= [self storeDatabaseColumnInArray: database: query:column];

    //close the database
    [database close];
    return nsarr;

}


- (FMDatabase *)openDatabase: (NSString *)databasename
{

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documents_dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *db_path = [documents_dir stringByAppendingPathComponent: databasename ];
    NSString *template_path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: databasename];

    if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:db_path])
        [fm copyItemAtPath:template_path toPath:db_path error:nil];
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:db_path];
    if (![db open])
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
    return db;
}
-(void) createAndCheckDatabase
{
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_databasePath];
    NSString *databasePathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName ];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:_databasePath error:nil];

}

-(NSMutableArray *) storeDatabaseColumnInArray:(FMDatabase *)database: (NSString *)sqlStatement :(NSString *)columnName
{

    NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [NSMutableArray array];
    FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery: sqlStatement];

    while([results next]) {

        NSString *rowValue = [results stringForColumn:columnName];

        [mutablearray addObject:results];
         NSLog(@"row value %@",rowValue);
    }

    //convert the nsmutable array to nsarray
 //   NSArray *temparr=[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutablearray];
    return mutablearray;

}

@end
```

The data in database is not displayed.

unable to access the database.

errors are

```
database    FMDatabase *    0x0757ed50
nsarr         NSMutableArray *  0x0718df40
```

Comment: It's very hard to figure out what the error is from what you posted, yet that would be *very very* useful for helping you.

Comment: when i am running this code...in App Delegate.h execution stops at MyDatabase *data=[MyDatabase new];
  NSMutableArray *nsarr=  [data OpenMyDatabase: @"select pic_name from exterior":@"pic_name"];
this line...and data in database is not displayed